# Application times out in browser but not in command line

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, shell

I'm building a web application using CodeIgniter and MySQL. I'm baffled by this one:

I have a MySQL View which pools for 3 tables, one of those tables has ~600,000 rows of data. On this view I make the following query:

```
SELECT *, AVG(value_avg) hourly_value_avg, AVG(count) hourly_count_avg, (AVG(value_avg) * AVG(count)) hourly_time_consumed FROM (`perf_view`) GROUP BY `event_id`
```

Through a MySQL client it takes about 5 seconds to come up with 30 results, through the command line, calling the exact controller and method which executes the query, it takes about the same, the problem is, when I hit the page in the browser, I get the following error:

```
Error Number: 2013
Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

Reading up on this error, I found out that it's probably a client error, ie the PHP is timing out, not the DB. I'm a little baffled by this, has anyone encountered the same issue?

I would really appreciate any help I can get :)

Comment: start your debugging efforts by googling the error message. You will often see many others have encountered it.

Comment: change the query for something very simple that would return a single record super quick and see if that works to verify that the connection is all good and start looking somewhere else.

Comment: @palako I did, and it works fine, this was working when the dataset was smaller.

Comment: @rambocoder I've been trying to debug this for 3 days now, and like any issue I have, I start with a Google search. I've come here because  I haven't found anything helpful. Thanks.

Comment: So if the query takes about 5 seconds, how long does it take to get the error? is it more than that? Check the  mysql.connect_timeout in your php.ini file and see if is set to 5 seconds or less.

Comment: I checked that, and it's set to 60 seconds :(

Answer (score 0):

In your controller constructor or any function, you could try extending the time and memory the script uses through codeigniters framework. It is possible to set these things with the following commands.

```
set_time_limit(0);     // set the execution time to any time. in my case infinite time
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');      // set the memory use to whatever here 256 megs
```

Your case sounds like it could be a memory issue. 600,000 records could easily breach the memory limit in your PHP configurations or your codeigniter configurations. Both are usually set kind of low and if your 600,000 record query returns a fair chunk of a table with many columns I can see a memory limit issue being worth checking into. Good Luck.